# How to get a div underneath another div in flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox, media-queries

For a homepage designed in flexbox, I am encountering a problem which I cannot solve in CSS, unfortunately. I also wonder whether it is doable at all in CSS only. If not, then I will need to find a solution in JS.

The website is mobile first. In the flex container there are an H2 element, 3 divs: .intro, .image and .text. In .text there are paragraphs and a button.

In the mobile and tablet queries all works fine, except for the desktop version where the .text div should go underneath the .intro div, which both go to the right of the .image div. Left and right should be 50% both. 
This is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 
.flex-container {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;  
    -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
}

.flex-container > * {
    padding: 10px;
    flex: 1 100%;
}

.text {
    text-align: left;
    background: cornflowerblue;
}

.intro {
    background: yellow;
}

.image {
    background: moccasin;
    height: 200px;
}

@media all and (min-width: 600px) {
    .image { flex: 1 0px; }
    .text    { flex: 1 0px; }
    .image { order: 1; } 
    .text    { order: 2; }
}

@media all and (min-width: 769px) {
    .flex-container :not(.image){
    -webkit-flex-flow: column nowrap;
    flex-flow: column nowrap;
}
    .intro { flex: 1 50%; }
    .image { flex: 12 0px; }
    .text    { flex: 1 50%; }
    .image { order: 1; }
    .intro { order: 2; }
    .text    { order: 3; }
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <div class="flex-container">
        <div class="intro">
            <p>Intro: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque sed ex turpis.</p>
        </div>
    <div class="image">Image</div>
        <div class="text">
            <p>Text: Cras luctus nibh lectus, in ullamcorper ex tempor eleifend. Nulla bibendum, eros a consequat vestibulum, orci massa fermentum quam, sed commodo nunc ex vitae nisl.</p>
            <button>click me</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's how it should look like:
[how the desktop media query should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ONDm.png)

Comment: flex can do the first 3 , the last you expect requires grid

Comment: Great, that works indeed. Only thing is that flexbox is more widespread. Caniuse still mentions a large global %. For now this will do. Many thanks G-Cyr!

Comment: try using `flex-direction: column; ` for desktop

Comment: OOH I see what you are doing. Yes I would try css grid instead: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Grids

Answer (score 1):

if you have nothing about grid, you may use it for the desktop layout :

```css
.flex-container {
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}

.flex-container>* {
  padding: 10px;
  flex: 1 100%;
}

.text {
  text-align: left;
  background: cornflowerblue;
}

.intro {
  background: yellow;
}

.image {
  background: moccasin;
  height: 200px;
}

@media all and (min-width: 600px) {
  .flex-container {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
  }
  .image {
    flex: 1 0px;
  }
  .text {
    flex: 1 0px;
  }
  .image {
    order: 1;
  }
  .text {
    order: 2;
  }
}

@media all and (min-width: 769px) {
  
  .flex-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  }
  .intro,
  .text {
    grid-column: 2;
  }
  .image {
    grid-row:1 / span 2
  }
}
```

```html
<h2>Title</h2>
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="intro">
    <p>Intro: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque sed ex turpis.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="image">Image</div>
  <div class="text">
    <p>Text: Cras luctus nibh lectus, in ullamcorper ex tempor eleifend. Nulla bibendum, eros a consequat vestibulum, orci massa fermentum quam, sed commodo nunc ex vitae nisl.</p>
    <button>click me</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

usefull link : https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/

Comment: May I add height: auto; to the last rule? Ie .image { grid-row:1 / span 2; height: auto; }. In that case the image keeps having the same height as the right part. Anyway, this has helped me a lot. Thanks again!

Comment: if you do not want the box image to grow, you may add : margin-bottom:auto; it will not be stretch to the bottom of its cell . not sure i understood your comment question :)